# How to add another xml file content into an existing xml creation using groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a requirement where I am collecting system and some product specific information, so is there a way I can append the already existing xml's content to the `product` tag, in my xml builder?

My test code to create a xml using groovy

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.*

def writer = new StringWriter()  
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer) 

def xml=new XmlSlurper().parse("E:\\DomainMeta.xml")

builder.csm() { 
    system(osname:"linux", hostname:"panther")
    product()
    {
        //Here i'd like to add my xml content, starting with <DomainMeta>
    }

} 
println writer.toString()
```

My xml, which has to be copied into another xml which i am building above

```
<DomainMeta>    //there can be more dynamic information inside DomainMeta tag
<Gateways>
<NodeRef name="N_116489" host="panther" httpPort="18,448" port="18,449" />
</Gateways>
<OptionGroup name="DomainOptions">
    <Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" ></Option>
</OptionGroup>
<OptionGroup name="NodeOptions">
    <Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" ></Option>
</OptionGroup>  
</DomainMeta>
```

Desired output

```
<csm>
  <system osname='linux' hostname='panther' />
  <product>
    <DomainMeta>
    <Gateways>
    <NodeRef name="N_116489" host="panther" httpPort="18,448" port="18,449" />
    </Gateways>
    <OptionGroup name="DomainOptions">
        <Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" ></Option>
    </OptionGroup>
    <OptionGroup name="NodeOptions">
        <Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" ></Option>
    </OptionGroup>
    </DomainMeta>
  </product>
</csm>
```

**Update**

One more Problem, The question that i asked is answered by tim_yates but i am facing another problem here, the xml data which comes as a dump is in a format given below, @tim: can you help?

```
&lt;DomainMeta&gt;
&lt;Gateways&gt;
&lt;NodeRef name="N_116489" host="panther" httpPort="18,448" port="18,449" /&gt;
&lt;/Gateways&gt;
&lt;OptionGroup name="DomainOptions"&gt;
    &lt;Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" &gt;&lt;/Option&gt;
&lt;/OptionGroup&gt;
&lt;OptionGroup name="NodeOptions"&gt;
    &lt;Option name="LicenseUsageDetailMinDays" value="90" &gt;&lt;/Option&gt;
&lt;/OptionGroup&gt;  
&lt;/DomainMeta&gt;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it if you use StreamingMarkupBuilder like so:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse("E:\\DomainMeta.xml")

def out = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { 
  csl {
    system(osname:"linux", hostname:"panther")
    product() {
       mkp.yield xml
    }
  }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( out )
```

#### Edit -- Answer to secondary unrelated question

If you have that in a variable called `txt`, you should be able to do:

```
txt = txt.replace( '&lt;', '<' )
         .replace( '&gt;', '>' )
```

Then, pass the `txt` to `XmlSlurper.parseText()`

Though really, I'd say that this is an issue with the thing that is writing the source out so it is unusable as xml, but pretty on the web.

Comment: Thanks your answer actually solves my problem, but there is 1 more hitch, i just found out, can you please have a look at my update part of question?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon so you're grabbing the xml formatted for the web?

Comment: sorry i did not understand "for the web".. it is a web application though, so the generated xml will be parsed by the wep app to display information neatly

Comment: @AbhishekSimon as a rule, showing xml to the end user makes little sense, but hopefully my addition to my answer has helped

Comment: Though I have marked your solution as answer, but i found a problem where the xml may contain CDATA section.. so under that it should not replace `&lt;` & `&gt;`

Comment: As I said before, having to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` shouldn't happen, and is indicative of something wrong in your pipeline...  Either you are getting hold of data that has been converted to html for viewing rather than the xml itself, or something else is wrong.  You shouldn't need to do it...

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did

The problem, during xml markup builder if we give a string containing xml/html content it converts `<` & `>` to `&lt;` & `&gt;` respectively so in order to avoid this replacing all `&lt;` & `&gt;` with `<` & `>` might work, but sometimes you have CDATA section which might again contain <, which i don't want to replace, so i used `mkp.yieldUnescaped content`

```
File domainMetaFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/DomainMeta.xml")

if ( domainMetaFile.exists( ) )
{
    String content = domainMetaFile.getText()
    def rootNode= domainMetaFile.readLines().get(0)  
//getting the root node
    def node=rootNode.find("[\\w\\d]+")
    content=content.replaceAll("</"+node+">","").replaceAll("<"+node+">","")     
//removing the root node from the string $content
    csm."$node"{mkp.yieldUnescaped content}  
//adding $content to my existing xml builder (csm)
//Here i am using mkp.yieldUnescaped content to ignore escaping of HTML/XML characters

}
else
csm.DomainMeta(na){}
```